# Looping through a list inside a HTML.DropDownList C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to loop through a list inside of a drop down list but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code.

```
public class AnimalHandler
{
    public List<string> DogBreeds = new List<string>()
    {
       "Affenpinscher","Lhasa Apso","Shitzu", "Tibetan Terrier"
    }
}
```

And then in the view

```
Project1.Models.AnimalHandler animal = new Project1.Models.AnimalHandler();

@Html.DropDownList("breed", new List<SelectListItem> { 
    foreach(var item in animal.DogBreeds)
    {
          new SelectListItem {Text="item", Value=""},
    }
    new SelectListItem {Text="Choose a Breed", Value=""}
})
```

My thought behind it would be that var item would loop through all the items in the DogBreeds however there seems to be an error and I can't figure out what it could be.

Perhaps there is another **SIMPLE** way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("breed", new SelectList(animal.DogBreeds), "Choose a breed")
```

---

From comments, to set a selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownList("breed", new SelectList(animal.DogBreeds, 
                                             "Great Dane"), 
                                              "Choose a breed")
```

Where you get your selected value from is down to you.

Comment: P.S. You don't state in your example how the code in AnimalHandler links up with your Animal class.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you :) +1

Comment: Is it really as simple as that?! That's ridiculous haha. The only problem I can possibly see, is the value that is passed. Is there a way to change the value given. I'm planning the URL structue to look like /Dogs/Grey-Hound for example.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "breed", 
    animal.DogBreeds.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }), 
    "Choose a Breed")
```